# Is it true that a dihedral group is nonabelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, dihedral-groups

Is it true that a dihedral group is nonabelian?

I'm not sure if the result is true. I checked it for some lower order and I think the result may correct.

But I failed to prove/disprove the result.

Comment: What happens if you first do the smallest possible rotation and then reflect in some line? What happens if you first reflect in that same line and then do that rotation?

Comment: There are many equivalent definition about dihedral group. What definition did you have learn?

Comment: The easier the question, the more identical answers. What a nonsense ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the dihedral groups $D_n$ are nonabelian for $n\ge 3$. It is generated by a rotation $r$ with $r^n=1$ and a reflection $s$ with $s^2=1$. However, you can easily check that a rotation and a reflection will not commute in general. We have
$sr=r^{-1}s$ instead for $D_n$ with this presentation.

Answer (score 3):

$D_3$, i.e, the dihedral group of a triangle is isomorphic to $S_3$ which is non-abelian. It can be shown that this is true for $n \geq 3$.

Remark: Some people denote the dihedral group by $D_{2n}$ which is based on the fact the order is $2n$, while some people denote it by $D_n$.

Comment: That's a good point to mention about notation!

Answer (score 3):

The dihedral groups for $n=1$ and $n=2$ are abelian; for $n\geq 3$, the dihedral groups are nonabelian ([this is mentioned on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group#Small_dihedral_groups)).

Answer (score 0):

Dihedral group of order $2n$ has the presentation

$$\langle x,y \mid x^n=y^2=e,yxy=x^{-1}\rangle$$

When $n=1$, we have $x=e$ and thus it is a group of order 2.

When $n=2$, we have $yxy=x$ and so $xy=yx$. Thus it is abelian.

But when $n\geq 3$, then $yxy=x^{n-1}$ and so $xy=yx^{n-1} \neq yx$. Thus it is not abelian.

Comment: You need to explain why the _inequality_ holds.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are two element of the group and $xy\neq yx$, means they do not commute, and so it is not an abelian group.

Comment: @deibor: You cannot conclude from a group presentation that certain relations do not hold. For example, even when a presentation contains something like $x^3=1$, it doesn't mean that the order of $x$ is three. In fact, other relations might imply that $x=1$. The general word problem for groups is undecidable.

Comment: @Martin What you say is true, but in this specific case we are fine. This is because we know that these relations hold and we know that $x$ has order $n$. If $yx^{n-1}=yx$ then we would have $x^2=1$ so $n\leq 2$.

Comment: The presentation $\langle x,y∣x^n=y^2=e,yxy=x−1\rangle$, has been taken as an equivalent definition of dihedral group of order $2n$ by many authors of many text book. Also it is an equivalent definition on wikipedia and groupprop.

Comment: @deibor Just saying it is a definition does not address the points in the comments. You need to persuade us that in the group you have given us $x$ is not simply an element of order two (and so commutes with $y$). One way to prove this (which is what my comment about it trying to say) is that if you can find a structure $S$ which the group given by this presentation acts on and $x$ has order $n$ in this action then you are done. Take $S$ to be a regular $n$-gon and you are done. Without doing something like that your answer is incomplete...

Comment: (On the other hand, if you *were* to do something like that then the answer would be rather good and I would upvote it.)

Comment: @Martin: Let $S$ be a set and let $F_S$ be the free group on $S$. Let $R$ be a set of words on $S$, so $R$ naturally gives a subset of $F_S$. Let $N$ to be the normal closure of $R$ in $F_S$. The group $\langle S\mid R \rangle$ is then defined as the quotient group

    $$\langle S \mid R \rangle = F_S / N.$$

TA group G is said to have the presentation $\langle S\mid R \rangle$ if G is isomorphic to $\langle S\mid R \rangle$.

Comment: @deibor Just shouting "presentation" isn't helping - I am certain that Martin Brandenburg knows the definition of a presentation. The point he is trying to make is that presentations are nasty and you cannot just say that an element has the given "obvious" order as you have just done. For example, consider the following group. $$\langle x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5; x_1x_2=x_3, x_2x_3=x_4, x_3x_4=x_5, x_4x_5=x_1, x_5x_1=x_2\rangle$$ "Clearly" all elements have infinite order. But no, this presentation defines the cyclic group of order 11 (which is far from obvious!).

Comment: In the presentation that i have given, $x$ is an element of order $n$. I think that is not difficult to show. From the definition of presentation, also we can show that $n$ is an element of order $n$.

Comment: Yes, noone is disputing the fact that $x$ is an element of order $n$. However, this needs to be shown (which isn't difficult, but isn't obvious either). Also, there is no element denoted by $n$...

Answer (score 0):

My picture for $D_4$ shows $fr = r^{-1}f$ and **not** $rf$.
See Zev Chonoles's exquisite pictures at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/686175/53934 too.

[image]